# Generate a Rails view on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my form structure defined on a database. How can I generate an erb file on the fly with all the form fields being pulled from the database rather than having them being hand-coded into the erb file?

Comment: How do you have your form structured in the database?

Comment: It's quite simple actually. You just fetch fields metadata and, for each field in this form, render corresponding control type. The view itself is ~5 lines of code (you'll need some more code in view helpers/form builders).

Answer (score 1):

```
rails g scaffold User field:string field2:string field3:text --migration=false --skip
```

Change user to the Modelname u use, also change the fields to the fields u use in the database.

This will skip files that already exist